# Mixing data from multiple JSON files

Tags: arrays, json

I'm building a project that loads Fantasy Football stats of players. I'm using NFL.com's API and I'm stuck right now. While doing some searching I saw some similar topics already answered on stackoverflow, but they didn't quite fit my needs.

Here's the links to the JSON files I'm using:

http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?statType=seasonStats&season=2014&week=1&format=json
http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?statType=seasonStats&season=2014&week=2&format=json
http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?statType=seasonStats&season=2014&week=3&format=json

Here's a link to an unflattened version so you can actually see the structure properly: http://codebin.org/view/89722b2e

As you can see, each of those links is picking a different week of the season. The name, position, and team I only need to pull once, but I need to pull the weekly stats from each JSON file for each player. I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing it.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?statType=seasonStats&season=2014&week=1&format=json");
$data = json_decode($json);
$path = $data->players;

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Season Points</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($path as $player) {
        $parts = explode(" ", $player->name);
        $lastname = array_pop($parts);
        $firstname = implode(" ", $parts);
        $player->name = $lastname.", ".$firstname;
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $player->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $player->teamAbbr; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $player->position; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $player->seasonPts; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $player->weekPts; ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The blank  is being saved for the week 2 points. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of pulling all these stats on every request, why don't you pull them once each week, or once on a set schedule, and cache the results somewhere. Build a script that just does that task -> gets your data and puts it into the format YOU want. Then have your view code work with YOUR format. Would be much more efficient, and your pages will load much faster.

Comment: I had considered doing that because like you say, it would be more efficient and load faster than pulling the stats on every request. That would work fine for older stats, but when the season starts those stats will be updated very often and other than doing using a cron job like every 5-10 minutes to update the database, it won't be updated enough.

Comment: How many people will be hitting your page at a time?

Comment: Well, right now it's about 100-200 per day, but I'm expecting more once I get this finished up. It should draw in more traffic. I couldn't say how many are hitting at a time.

Comment: So, running 1 task that updates the stats every 1 minute would be more efficient than 100 people refreshing the page every 1-2 minutes during game time, and it having to fetch those stats for each request. Cache the stats man. It'll scale better - I promise you. It also separates concerns, and makes your display logic easier/cleaner.

Comment: You're right. I'm going to do that. I think not only will it load faster for the users and the server, but it'll be easier to code. Thanks for your help and suggestions.